# modify or edit ppt template in .net

Tags: asp.net, openxml

I have an website which sends mail with attachment which is an ppt presentation.
I have that ppt template stored in my application. 
Based on the selection made by the user, i need to modify the template content i.e. namely add a text to that ppt template and send it as an attachment.
Someone please tell me how to edit or modify the ppt template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write down the ppt template on .net code behind, I have use the solution from shotdev, it's in vb.net:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Const wdColorLightGreen = &HCCFFCC
Const wdColorBlue = &HCCFFCC

Dim ppApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres As Presentation
Dim ppSlide1, ppSlide2, ppSlide3, ppSlide4 As Slide
Dim ppName As String = "MyPP/MyPPt.ppt"
Dim ppDoc As String = "shotdev.ppt"

ppApp.Visible = True

ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(Server.MapPath(ppDoc))

ppSlide1 = ppPres.Slides(1)
'*** AddTextbox, objControl.Left,objControl.Top,objControl.Width,objControl.Height ***'
ppSlide1.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 50, 100, 700, 100) '***4
ppSlide1.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "I Love ShotDev.Com 1"
ppSlide1.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
ppSlide1.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 10
ppSlide1.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = wdColorLightGreen

ppSlide1.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 50, 150, 700, 100)
ppSlide1.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "I Love ShotDev.Com 2"
ppSlide1.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
ppSlide1.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20

ppSlide1.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 50, 200, 700, 100)
ppSlide1.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "I Love ShotDev.Com 3"
ppSlide1.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
ppSlide1.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 30

ppSlide1.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 50, 250, 700, 100)
ppSlide1.Shapes(4).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "I Love ShotDev.Com 4"
ppSlide1.Shapes(4).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
ppSlide1.Shapes(4).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 40

ppSlide1.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 50, 300, 700, 100)
ppSlide1.Shapes(5).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "I Love ShotDev.Com 5"
ppSlide1.Shapes(5).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
ppSlide1.Shapes(5).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 50
ppSlide1.Shapes(5).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = wdColorBlue
ppSlide1.Shapes.AddPicture(Server.MapPath("logo.gif"), 0, 1, 310, 380, 100, 100) '*** Picture,Left,Top,Width,Height ***'

ppSlide2 = ppPres.Slides.Add(2, 3)
ppSlide2.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "www.ShotDev.Com Version"
ppSlide2.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = wdColorBlue
ppSlide2.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Version 2009" & vbCr & _
"Version 2009" & vbCr & "Version 2009" & vbCr & "Version 2009"
ppSlide2.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Version 2010" & vbCr & _
"Version 2010" & vbCr & "Version 2010" & vbCr & "Version 2010"

ppSlide3 = ppPres.Slides.Add(3, 4)
ppSlide3.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "We Love ShotDev.Com"
ppSlide3.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = wdColorBlue

ppSlide4 = ppPres.Slides.Add(4, 5)
ppSlide4.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "We Love ShotDev.Com"
ppSlide4.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = wdColorBlue
ppSlide4.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "2006" & vbCr & "2007" & vbCr & "2008" & vbCr & "2009" & vbCr & "2010"

ppApp.Presentations(1).SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ppName))
ppApp.Quit()
ppApp = Nothing

Me.lblText.Text = "PowerPoint Created <a href=" & ppName & ">Click here</a> to Download."

End Sub
End Class
```

you could refere to this : http://www.shotdev.com/aspnet/aspnet-vbnet-powerpoint/aspnet-vbnet-powerpoint-open-template-modify-edit-slides/

Answer (score 0):

Try the [MS interop assemblis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx).
In case you have `*.pptx` format you could also use  [openXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)